# Lambert Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I found the following problem on the net. Looks like "might be a Lambert", but I'm not sure. I have managed to reduce it a bit.

```
log[4x-12]- 18 = -3(-1/2)^x

log[4(x-3)] - 18 = -3(-1/2)^x

log 4 + log(x+3) - 18  = -3(-1/2)^x

0.6   + log(x+3) - 18  = -3(-1/2)^x

        log (x+3) -17.4 = -3(-1/2)^x
         
          (log (x+3))            (-3(-1/2)^x)  
       10^                  = 10^             + 10^(17.4)   Not sure if this step is valid. 

       log (x+3)           =  10^(-3(-1/2)^x) + 2.511886    Can't proceed from here. Not sure 
                                                            this equation is "doable" Any help 
                                                            appreciated.  I'm filling in the 
                                                            blanks in my deficient 
                                                            mathematical knowledge. Thanks
```

Comment: You mean bringing if possible your expression into something involving ["Lambert W" function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) ?

Comment: No, Jean Marie. I'm not sure at all what type of an equation this is--whether it is Lambert or should be solved otherwise.  Not sure if it can even be solved by conventional methods.   I did try to plot y = -3(-1/2)^x.  Got an error something like "Unable to proceed with problem".

Comment: Yes, as I said it, $(-1/2)^x$ is meaningless in the real domain. An advice: do not loose any more time on this "exercise": you find strange things sometimes on the net...